# Why my application is not running in heroku after getting build successful

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications, procfile

[image: Image of application after launching]I have developed a python app using flask framework, i am deploying the same in Heroku but i am getting the application error after successful build. My app is running in localhost. What's the issue, where i am wrong, and how to resolve the problem.

Procfile content:

> web: python Flask/app.py, i also tried web: python app.py but it didn't work.

Requirments.txt:

> flask==0.12

More specifically i am not using gunicorn.

LogFile details in heroku:

```
Python app detected
-----> Installing python-2.7.13
   $ pip install -r requirements.txt
    Collecting flask==0.12 (from -r /tmp/build_ae4a1daf2328eb128abf7b576e0858c1/requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading Flask-0.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82kB)
    Collecting itsdangerous>=0.21 (from flask==0.12->-r /tmp/build_ae4a1daf2328eb128abf7b576e0858c1/requirements.txt (line 1))
     Downloading itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46kB)
   Collecting Werkzeug>=0.7 (from flask==0.12->-r /tmp/build_ae4a1daf2328eb128abf7b576e0858c1/requirements.txt (line 1))
     Downloading Werkzeug-0.12.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (312kB)
   Collecting Jinja2>=2.4 (from flask==0.12->-r /tmp/build_ae4a1daf2328eb128abf7b576e0858c1/requirements.txt (line 1))
     Downloading Jinja2-2.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (340kB)
   Collecting click>=2.0 (from flask==0.12->-r /tmp/build_ae4a1daf2328eb128abf7b576e0858c1/requirements.txt (line 1))
     Downloading click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
   Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask==0.12->-r /tmp/build_ae4a1daf2328eb128abf7b576e0858c1/requirements.txt (line 1))
     Downloading MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
   Installing collected packages: itsdangerous, Werkzeug, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, click, flask
     Running setup.py install for itsdangerous: started
       Running setup.py install for itsdangerous: finished with status 'done'
     Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe: started
       Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe: finished with status 'done'
   Successfully installed Jinja2-2.9.5 MarkupSafe-1.0 Werkzeug-0.12.1 click-6.7 flask-0.12 itsdangerous-0.24
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
   Done: 37.7M
-----> Launching...
   Released v3
   https://guarded-tundra-18526.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

LogFile doesn't show any error. Then why i am not able to run my app.

Comment: And what is happening when you trye to run your app? Do you have some errors? Can you post error logs?

Comment: I already posted LogFie of heroku and it shows no error even the app is getting launched after that it gives application error.

Comment: Run `heroku logs --tail` in another terminal to see if the Procfile command is hitting any errors at launch.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue with the host and port parameters for the "run" method of the Flask instance (app).

Set the host to "0.0.0.0" instead of  "127.0.0.1" to allow any IP to access the app (rather than only locally)

The port by default is 5000 in flask but Heroku dynamically assigns the app a port so hard coding it won't work.

Run the app as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port)
```

The port can then be obtained from the Heroku PORT env var.